HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found ...because the query string is too long, without C# code issue
I have this problem with a .NET Framework web application.

HTTP Error 404.15 – Not Found. The request filtering module is
configured to deny a request where the query string is too long

However, it is somehow still different as it is not caused by the C# code as my colleague does not have this issue using the same code. Thus, the approved solution does not work for me. The application behaviour depends on IIS settings. So maybe I need to search there? How to fix an issue like this?

Back to the basic, and you should use the browser's developer tools to see into the actual requests/responses and see what exactly are the query strings. Usually people make that part of the question.

In the IIS Request Filtering module, try increasing the maximum query string length.
By default, this value is set to 2048 characters. Increase this value to accommodate longer query strings used by your application. For example, you can set it to 4096 or higher as needed. Restart IIS to ensure that all settings take effect.
